# Getting all rows' li elements in a table

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on All, I want to get all the `li` elements in different rows of table. Here I get all the `li` elements of one row.

```
<ul class="clsInfo">
  <li id="liAll" onclick="Activelink(this);">
    <a href="#">
      <label id="lblAll">All</label>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Code:

```
function Activelink(sender) {
    var a_elements = sender.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0, len = a_elements.length; i < len; i++) {
        a_elements[i].style.color = 'black';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, improve it.

Comment: where is your table? parent element of `sender` seems to be `<ul>` here...

Answer (score 1):

You describe `li` elements and tables, but your code is setting the properties of `a` (anchor) tags. If your "All" link is nested in a table that we can't see in the html sample, then you need to find it with a loop:

```
function findParentalTable(el) {
  var current = el;
  while((current !== document) && (current.tagName != "TABLE")) {
    current = current.parentNode;
  }
  return current;
}
```

Then your code would be

```
function Activelink(sender) {
  var parentalTable = findParentalTable(sender);
  var a_elements = parentalTable.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0, len = a_elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    a_elements[i].style.color = 'black';
  }
}
```

The parent node of an element is another DOM element, and all DOM elements have the property tagName, which is the uppercase tag string, like TABLE. The while loop is just walking up the DOM tree looking for a `<table>` tag. As soon as it finds a table tag, the current.tagName will be TABLE and the condition will fail, permitting the function to return the element. Just in case there is no table element above the element passed to `findParentalTable`, I also check that we haven't reached the top of the DOM, the `document` node; `!==` checks for an exact reference match (generally good practice to use `!==` and `===`).

Comment: Thank you Very Much its working fine but i have small doubt  .  What is the use of this  (current !== document) && (current.tagName != "TABLE")